# Apache Storm: Remembering old number of output fields for spout

Tags: serialization, storage, cluster-computing, apache-storm

After changing a spouts declaration from a single field output to two the cluster seems to remember its old declaration of output. For example

```
declarer.declare(new Fields("userTask"));
```

To

```
declarer.declare(new Fields("tupleTrackingId","userTask"));
```

This spout has be serialized. Which is remembered also.

**The error in the log states**

```
Tuple created with wrong number of fields. Expected 1 fields but got 2 fields
```

But now it has the new declaration.

**Questions**
Is there a way to clear history of a storm cluster? Or clear the historically generated serialized object?

Or if this another issue?

For sanity here is the spout output.

```
outputCollector.emit(new Values(msgID, task), msgID);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because I had an original compiled jar of the same program in the storm directory, from previous building and deploying when testing set up of the cluster.

What happens is any jars in this file were included when starting Nimbus therefore had a reference to this old jar, messing up with Serialization of a changed object. You can view this by looking at the parameters passed when starting Nimbus.

**To Note**
Do not put jars in the Storm folder as may cause you issues which are difficult to track down.

Answer (score 0):

Nimbus buffers submitted topologies in `storm.local.dir`. You should be able to delete the buffered topology there (ie, a jar file). **But be careful:** deleting "wrong" files will interrupt running topologies!

Comment: Thanks but I attempted that but it still doesnt work. Cleared Jars from here: /usr/local/storm/storm-local/nimbus/inbox

Comment: Are you sure, that the jar file you submit was updated properly containing the new spout code?